# Does UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) support disk with size lower than 2TB?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi, gpt

I'm trying to use UEFI on my PC with disk less than 2TB. It's only 466GB and running Windows 10 32 bit. Can I boot with UEFI on a PC that has disk with size lower than 2TB?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Not long ago all laptops with SSD only had much less than that and they were and are all UEFI.

Comment: So I only need to change to GPT on my 32-bit pc?

Comment: *So I only need to change to GPT on my 32-bit pc?* No, of course not but that isn't in the question. Running a 32-bit OS doesn't mean the architecture can't be 64-bit, the other way around it's not possible. With the exception of early Bay Trail CPUs (and much older Macs) with a 32-bit UEFI (but an otherwise 64-bit hardware in the case of Bay Trails), UEFI = 64-bit.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia.  Your statement that "UEFI = 64-bit"  is false.  UEFI firmware and binaries can be build for IA32, 32-bit ARM and more.  In fact, Intel sells motherboards with 64-bit CPU and 32-bit UEFI firmware.  Ex. Intel Galileo and Intel MinnowBoard.

Comment: @fpmurphy Are you sure? I want to move to UEFI. My motherboard is Foxconn, so I'm not sure should I move to or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the requirements backwards – having a 2TB+ disk requires GPT, but not the other way around. Neither UEFI nor GPT impose a minimum disk size anywhere near that.

Any size disk can be used with GPT, and any disk that can fit an EFI System Partition can be used with UEFI, so the practical minimum size is probably around several *megabytes.*